# How do I find out my fine-tunes models using Python?

Tags: python, openai-api

Hi can anyone help me with Python code to list my fine-tunes models?
Is there an equivalent to the

```
openai.file.list()
```

I have tried

**openai.models.list()**

**openai.fine-tunes.list()**

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. This works for me.

```py
openai.FineTune.list()
```

Comment: Thank you Christopher. This works nicely.